# How to display the permissions of a new file in the status line of the Vim editor?

Tags: permissions, files, vim, editors, umask

With the following piece of code I get the permissions for an existing file:

```
augroup Get_file_perm
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter,FileChangedShell * let w:file_perm=getfperm(expand('%:p'))
augroup END
" Output, e.g.: rw-rw-r--
set statusline=%{w:file_perm}
```

Unfortunately the `getfperm` function returns the empty string (`""`) for the current file path (`'%:p'`) if it doesn't exist. I had expected the file permissions calculated from the `umask`.

Comment: Doesn't `%:p` just return the directory the file is currently in? Try just `%`, instead. Also, what's wrong with (from command mode): `:!ls -l %`

Comment: With the `autochdir` option enabled `expand('%')` expands only to the file's `basename`. With the `:p` modifier the absolute path is coerced. `:h expand` is your friend.

Comment: Also I want to see the file permissions at first glance, without any key stroke.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there doesn't exist a Vim function that accomplishes what you're asking for. But I came up with my `s:Get_file_perm` function whose result I assign to the `w:file_perm` variable:

```
" ...
let w:file_perm=<sid>Get_file_perm()
" ...
function! s:Get_file_perm()
  let a=getfperm(expand('%:p'))
  if strlen(a)
    return a
  else
     let b=printf("%o", xor(0777,system("umask")))
     let c=""
     for d in [0, 1, 2]
       let c.=and(b[d], 4) ? "r" : "-"
       let c.=and(b[d], 2) ? "w" : "-"
       let c.=and(b[d], 1) ? "x" : "-"
     endfor
     return c
   endif
 endfunction
```

The function checks (`if`) to see if the permissions (`getfperm`) for the current file path (`'%:p'`) exist (`strlen`). In the case of a new file (`""`) the `else`-block bitwise subtracts (`xor`) the octal `umask` from the octal literal `0777` (`rwxrwxrwx`) – all permission bits set.

For the owner- (`0`) , group- (`1`) and permissions for others (`2`) it iteratively (`for`) checks for each read- (`4`), write- (`2`) and execute (`1`) bit that it is set (`and`). If the corresponding bit is set it appends (`.=`) `"r"`, `"w"` and `"x"` to the `c` variable, respectively. Else `"-"` is appended to symbolize that the respective operation is not permitted.

Comment: You're talking to yourself, man.. :-/

Comment: Its my second I. Sorry bro.

Comment: Keep talking, sometimes that is the best way to solve a problem if nobody else answers the question ;)  But on the other hand sometimes it is better just update the question with more information....